# how to use third party extension in sencha touch

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I am trying to use third party extension on this [link](https://market.sencha.com/users/21/extensions/43) for only `time` field. How can I use it in sencha touch 2.1?

**Edit**

I added the extension in `ux\picker` and then I used following code

```
Ext.define('HB.view.Search', {
extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
xtype: 'search',

Ext.require(['Ext.ux.picker.DateTimePicker']),

config: {
    title: 'Search',
    layout: 'fit',
    scrollable: true,
    styleHtmlContent: true,
    styleHtmlCls: 'searchpage',
    //html: ['<h1>Welcome to MyApp</h1>'].join(''),

    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'titlebar',
            title: 'Search Page',
            docked: 'top'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            name: 'from',
            placeHolder: 'From'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            name: 'to',
            placeHolder: 'To'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'datepickerfield',
            name: 'date',
            value: new Date()
        },
        {
            xtype: 'datetimepickerfield',
            name: 'time',
            value: new Date()
        }
    ]
},

//style: 'height:' + (Ext.getBody().getHeight()) + 'px;'
height: Ext.getBody().getHeight()
});
```

But it gives me this error

```
GET http://localhost/HelsinkiBus/touch/src/DateTimePicker.js?_dc=1357800622746 404 (Not Found) 
Uncaught Error: [Ext.Loader] Failed loading 'touch/src/DateTimePicker.js', please verify that the file exists
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just place the files from the `ux` folder in `ux\picker` folder in your project and use `xtype: 'datetimepickerfield'`.
Before you can use this component you need to load the files needed first. You can do this with [`Ext.require`](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.Loader-method-require)

Comment: There are two subfolders inside `ux` i.e. `auth` and `auth2`. So do I need put this inside one of those subfolders? There is no `picker` subfolder inside `ux`.

Comment: make one :)! This is because the extension uses Ext.ux.picker as namespace.

Comment: @A1rPun could you please check my update above. I am having problem with `Ext.requires`.

Comment: Check the link in my answer. you are using Ext.require wrong, use it like this before you define something `Ext.require(['Ext.ux.picker.DateTimePicker']);`

Comment: I did it what you said please check my updated code but it does not work either. I also checked that link in your answer since I am new to sencha touch so it is difficult to understand this without proper example.

Comment: I can understand that. Try to learn from the docs :) but on your problem: **place Ext.require on top of your page** after Ext.onready

Comment: You mean I should use it before `Ext.define()`? If yes then I use that way but it shows this error `Uncaught Error: [Ext.createByAlias] Cannot create an instance of unrecognized alias: widget.datetimepickerfield`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22503/discussion-between-a1rpun-and-x4ph4r)

Answer (score 2):

It is Ext.require(['Ext.ux.field.DateTimePicker']);.

DateTimePicker -> ux/field/DateTimePicker

DateTime -> ux/picker/DateTime

I wasted 6 hours to find this issue.